# CSS rules are not working

Tags: css

Hi I'm trying to learn css. But for my page , the used styles are not working. Here below shows the script I used. Can some one please let me know the issue that I had made.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

    button{

        .big{
            font-size:8px;
        }


        .small{
            font-size:8px;
        }

        #green{
            color:green;
        }       

    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
<button class="big">Button 1</button>
<button id="green" class="small">Button 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.big, .small {
    font-size:8px;
}

#green{
     color:green;
}
```

```html
<button class="big">Button 1</button>
<button id="green" class="small">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: You have made two changes in the code - one is probably not intended (combining the rules for `.big` and `.small` - the current font size only seems to be a proof of concept), the other one is the actual error. Your answer would be better if you pointed out the syntax error - enclosing the rules in a `button { }` block.

Answer (score 1):

You have enclosed the whole CSS in the button { } which is not required and is not the proper syntax. Remove the outer button { } from your CSS. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the button in the style tag. Also remove the corresponding parentheses. So you should be left with the below code in the style tag.

```
    .big{
        font-size:8px;
    }


    .small{
        font-size:8px;
    }

    #green{
        color:green;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry. I am new to this.

Comment: You can remove the **button** in the style tag. Also remove the corresponding parentheses. So you should be left with the below code in the style tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
      .big{
         font-size:8px;
       }
        .small{
            font-size:8px;
        }

        #green{
            color:green;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="big">Button 1</button>
<button id="green" class="small">Button 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```